# How to remap capslock key in Wayland?

Tags: gnome, wayland

I am unable to remap the Capslock key in Wayland (gnome) to Escape. I've tried Gnome Tweaks and

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"`

Neither causes the Capslock key to emit Escape key presses. I am able to do this on Xorg, but it does not work in Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf):

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:swapescape']"
```

Comment: Doesn't do exactly what OP requested.  This swaps caps and esc, (I think) OP wanted just an additional esc key.

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings` worked for me (debian bullseye, gnome + wayland). Perhaps you need to escape the value differently?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \[\'caps:escape\'\]
```

But these settings are not well documented.
Being a n00b with gsettings, I naively hoped `range` would show legal values for `xkb-options`.

```
---------- me@my-desktop:~ ----------
$ gsettings range  org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
type as                        <-- not informative

---------- me@my-desktop:~ ----------
$ gsettings describe  org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
List of XKB options. Each option is an XKB option string as defined by xkeyboard-config’s rules files.
```

A precious clue!

```
---------- me@my-desktop:~ ----------
$ more /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep caps:
  caps:internal        Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:internal_nocancel Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift does not affect Caps Lock
  caps:shift           Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:shift_nocancel  Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift does not affect Caps Lock
  caps:capslock        Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters
  caps:shiftlock       Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock (affects all keys)
  caps:swapescape      Swap ESC and Caps Lock
  caps:escape          Make Caps Lock an additional Esc
  caps:escape_shifted_capslock Make unmodified Caps Lock an additional Esc, but Shift + Caps Lock behaves like regular Caps Lock
  caps:backspace       Make Caps Lock an additional Backspace
  caps:super           Make Caps Lock an additional Super
  caps:hyper           Make Caps Lock an additional Hyper
  caps:menu            Make Caps Lock an additional Menu key
  caps:numlock         Make Caps Lock an additional Num Lock
  caps:ctrl_modifier   Caps Lock is also a Ctrl
  caps:none            Caps Lock is disabled
```